# Spring scheduled cron between 3:00 to 6:30

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I whould like to schedule a job every 5 minutes between 3:00 and 6:30.

This schedules my job every 5 minutes between 3:00 and 5:55:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 3-5 * * *")
```

But how do I get `@scheduled` to include the last 35 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 3-6,5 * * *")
```